# Tool for quickly creating project skeletons

Tags: c++, project-management

I has been a C++ and Python developer for a looong time, and after this many years the place I feel most comfortable for developing is the old good gvim and the command line. I was wondering if there is some sort of tool for setting up projects quickly. Something like generating a bunch of files where a few things can change their values: the project name for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many tools like this. [Cookiecutter](http://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is written in Python, and it has project templates for many languages and frameworks.

Comment: Cool! Did cookiecutter started in 2013? This question has been hanging here for a long time :-) . Glad to finally see a real answer!

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect that most [modern Integrated Development Environments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_integrated_development_environments#C.2FC.2B.2B) would support something like this.

Comment: Probably; but none of them fit me. I have used very powerful ones, like Visual Studio in all his editions, but as I told before, I usually integrate multiple languages and tools in one project, and no IDE make things easier there. So, that's why that's not the point of my question.

Comment: If at the end of the day you are going to use an IDE for coding, you should consider providing helper scripts to fit what the IDE generates to what you need. If you are going to code with an editor and the command line, then consider writing your own scripts with your past experience.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you write your own tool with some scripting language?

I have done it by tailoring GNU makefiles trying to push most of the logic outside of the project. Then have a small script that generates directories and writes simple makefiles that set a couple of variables and then includes the pre-generated makefiles.

You might want to consider instead of producing makefiles directly, generating files for other intermediate system like CMake or SCONS, as those will be able to abstract the differences from one system to another.

Comment: Even easier: copy an existing project directory structure to a new directory structure, clean out the unwanted files, run sed to modify the remaining ones.  I expect this is a few keystrokes with vim.

Comment: I have tried bjam, cmake and scons. And they are all great. Nowadays I use scons, which is a dream-replacement to Makefiles and it is so agile that I don't really feel the need for an IDE. But that said, every time I start a new project, I have to copy my scripts from an old one and modify them. It is really not big deal to make a script for that, but I was just curious to know if there is some established way...